# LIFO with stock splits

Tags: mariadb, data-versioning

### Background

I am managing a database containing my users' trading of financial products, stocks bonds, ETFs etc. The system offers simple bookkeeping functionality (create portfolio, create instrument, book a trade, book a cash flow ...) for my users, and some bulk features for the data admin user.

The system keeps track of trade / position performance ("pnl", profit-and-loss) and values sell-trades using the FIFO method, i.e. outgoing stock is valued at 'oldest' prices.

### Problem statement

Thru so-called corporate actions, a company manipulates their quantity of outstanding stock. An N-for-1 stock split, for example, results in N times the number of stock outstanding (at a price of 1/N of the pre-Split price), and the same holds for the number of stock in a given portfolio of a user, e.g. their quantities double during at a 2-for-1-split. Thus, the meaning of quantity may change over time, complicating the FIFO method in my database. I want to reconcile the ability to value a sale trade using the **FIFO method** with the concept of stock splits.

### Constraints

- hard constraint: Historical entries must be recoverable 'as is': Users want to see their historical trades' units as of that date.
- soft constraint: Data changes should be as local as possible, and be reversible: There should be no additional effect of adjusting for the 'same' stock split twice.

This is very a small project with <10 users and no interaction between the users' trades, concurrency is not an issue, I guess.

### Status Quo

For simplicity, I have dropped some entities such as `portfolio`, `instrument` etc. below.

In order to be able to calculate the FIFO value for the position in a financial asset (think: stocks), my system contains a table called `trade` that holds the history of each trade with trade quantity `qty`, unit price `prc`and a field `qty_allotable` that tells me how many units of each *buy* trade have not yet been sold off (i.e. not yet **allotted** to a sale). The relevant fields for my problem are:

```sql
CREATE TABLE db.trade (
   ,valuedate       DATE                    NOT NULL
   ,qty             DECIMAL(16,6)           NOT NULL
   ,prc             DECIMAL(12,6) UNSIGNED  NOT NULL
  ,qty_allotable    DECIMAL(16,6) UNSIGNED  NOT NULL
);
```

For example, let's buy 6 units of some stock on one day and another 4 units the next day (via some stored procedure not depicted here)

```
 valuedate   qty    prc  qty_allotable    
2021-08-02     6  10.00              6
2021-08-03     4  11.00              4
```

On day 3, we sell 7 units. Via FIFO, we value the outgoing units at

```
6 x 10 + 1 x 11 = 71.00
```

where the FIFO algorithm is implemented in some function, and we **deplete** the allotable quantity after the sale:

```
 valuedate   qty    prc  qty_allotable    
2021-08-02     5  10.00              0
2021-08-03     5  11.00              3
2021-08-04    -7  12.00              0 -- a sale is not allotable itself
```

where the table update algorithm is performed by some stored procedure. At each point in time, the total invested volume is a simple `SELECT(prc * qty_allotable) FROM ...`.

NB.: The setup requires trades to be entered (truly) in sequential order. If a user 'forgets' to enter a historical trade, I rebuild the whole trade table for the affected combination of user and instrument...

### Increased complexity due to stock splits

My question now is how to properly treat events that change the significance of a stock's quantity, e.g. a stock split. To make it tangible, say there's a 2-for-1 stock split on 2021-08-05, i.e. my remaining three units become six units (and the trading price halves), i.e. my **position** now is

```
 qty    unit_prc
   6        5.50  -- doubling the total qty, halving the prices.
```

### Perceived solutions

How should I incorporate this effect in the database? I think that I have identified a couple of options to follow,

##### 1. Fire and forget `WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING`

Introduce versioning to the `trade` table and simply update the **historical** `prc` and `qty_allotable` fields by the split factor.

Although I can retrieve original trades with this setup, I cannot 'roll back' to an earlier state without risking loss of trade data entered in the mean time.

##### 2. Introduce a table `corporate_actions` and adjusted business logic.

By introducing a table with an appropriate uniqueness index

```sql
CREATE TABLE db.corporate_action(
   ,valuedate       DATE                    NOT NULL
   ,split_factor    DECIMAL(12,6) UNSIGNED  NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_ca_unq ON db.corporate_action(value_date);
```

In our example, the table could look like this:

```
 valuedate   split_factor
 1970-01-01  1.000000  -- auto entry per instrument
 2021-08-05  2.000000
 2099-12-31  1.000000  -- auto entry per instrument
```

This way, I make sure that a 'double entry' cannot take place (thru the uniqueness index). In order to apply the FIFO method, I must adjust the historical quantities and prices through some view on the `corporate_actions table`, e.g.

```sql
SELECT 
     c1.valuedate
    ,EXP(-SUM(LOG(c2.split_factor))) as compound_factor
FROM       corporate_action c1 
INNER JOIN corporate_action c2 
        ON c1.valuedate <= c2.valuedate 
GROUP BY   c1.valuedate;
```

resulting in

```
valuedate   compound_factor
1970-01-01  0.5
2021-08-05  0.5
2099-12-31  1
```

Then, when calculating the FIFO price, I'd calculate `prc*compound_factor` and `qty/compound_factor` in order to properly calculate the outgoing value in a sell trade.

### Question

Do you think that either of the two perceived solutions is sensible, or can you propose another solution?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! [Ribbit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbit_(film))... Your question appears quite involved and would require a lot of work - it may well be closed as a "tip of the iceberg" question - but not by me! :-) You might want to start by having a look at F/LOSS trading software?